# Is it safe to use jQuery and jQuery-UI with Google Chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm going to write a simple chrome extension using jQuery and jQuery UI. Before I start, however, I want to know: what might happen if a web page that my extension is going to interact with also uses this libraries? Can there be any conflicts (e.g. CSS for my jQuery-UI theme messing up the page's jQuery-UI theme)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there can be conflicts, however you can prevent them. When you are setting up a theme, you need to download it with a namespace(you can find that setting in the right column of the jquery ui custom download page), and then use that namespace in your extension. The only possible issue at that point is if the site that is being viewed uses the same namespace that you choose, so make sure you choose something that won't have that problem.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript is sandboxed so there will be no conflicts, but CSS isn't, so any styles on parent site will affect your styling and vice versa (aka a nightmare).

Answer (score 0):

It depends what type of extension you are making. If you are making a replacement for an existing Chrome page, well, it will be a full replacement (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/override.html). If it is a popup through either page (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/pageAction.html) or browser (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html) action, then again, you will have no conflicts because all of your code is sandboxed to itself.

The only time I can think of that you will run into an issue is if you are using content scripts (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html), or actually injecting your code into the page by other means. Then, yes there could be conflicts, as the browser now runs your code along side the web sites code. Depending on what you need to do, you could try injecting your code as an iframe, but that will also prevent it from interacting with said web page.

```
<iframe src="yourPageUrl" height="iframeHeight" width="iframeWidth" style="border:none;"></iframe>
```

So without knowing what your extension's purpose was, it would be hard to know exactly how to help.